# Rewrite profile in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have 2 user roles in my website ('Teachers' and 'Student'). I wanna change Teachers profile URL to site.com/teacher_username and Students change to site.com/student/username. How can I rewrite URLs ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily rewrite urls using the Wordpress `Rewrite API`.

Easy example:

```
function custom_rewrite_basic() {
  add_rewrite_rule('^leaf/([0-9]+)/?', 'index.php?page_id=$matches[1]', 
'top');
}

add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic');
```

You can find more information here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule

Comment: how can i use it for my simple URLs ?!